# sometimes I want to hide buttons in a DataGridViewButtonColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, visibility, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I have a `DataGridView` which was the subject of a previous question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083989/datagridview-datagridviewbuttoncolumn-doesnt-notice-a-real-button/25089129)). But sometimes the Button is `null`. This is fine. But if it is null, is there any way I can optionally remove/add (show/hide?) buttons to the `DataGridViewButtonColumn` of Buttons

like this:

```
+------------+------------+
| MyText     | MyButton   |
+------------+------------+
| "do this"  | (Yes)      |
| "do that"  | (Yes)      |
| FYI 'blah' |            | <---- this is where I optionally want no button
| "do other" | (Yes)      |
+------------+------------+
```

this is what I have tried so far ([based on this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083989/datagridview-datagridviewbuttoncolumn-doesnt-notice-a-real-button/25089129))

```
private void grdVerdict_CellFormat(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.ColumnIndex == grdChoice.Columns["yesbutton"].Index)
   {
       if (grdVerdict[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value == null)
       {
            //grdVerdict[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Visible = false; //<-says 'it is read only'
            //grdVerdict[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = new DataGridTextBox(); //<- draws 'mad red cross' over whole grid
            //((Button)grdVerdict[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]).Hide; //<- won't work
       }
       else
       {
          e.Value = ((Button)grdChoice[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value).Text;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What should be there in place of button?

Comment: just a blank nothing.. no button at all

Comment: Keep it simple - set it to null and ignore its being clicked..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same "problem" today. I also wanted to hide buttons of certain rows. After playing around with it for a while, I discovered a very simple and nice solution, that doesn't require any overloaded `paint()`-functions or similar stuff:

**Just assign a different `DataGridViewCellStyle` to those cells.**
The key is, that you set the `padding` property of this new style to a value that shifts the whole button out of the visible area of the cell.
That's it! :-)

Sample:

```
System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCellStyle^  dataGridViewCellStyle2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCellStyle());
dataGridViewCellStyle2->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(25, 0, 0, 0);

dgv1->Rows[0]->Cells[0]->Style = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
// The width of column 0 is 22.
// Instead of fixed 25, you could use `columnwidth + 1` also.
```

Comment: Sir, you are a genius! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: I recommend 'Column.Width + 1000' otherwise the button can become visible if the user maximize the form

Comment: Unnecessary complications require ingenious solutions. Brilliant!

Comment: Just tried it and it works!  @John A lot of screen widths are > 1000 pixels nowadays.  That said, perhaps even better would be to use top or bottom padding.  If your grid has non-resizable rows, the button would never become visible this way.  And needless to say, you will probably want to define the cell style in a class member variable, so that you need only to set it up once.

Comment: Eventually worked for me, but I had add vertical padding like @Stewart suggested. I also had to edit the DataGridViewColumn in the Designer and set `Resizable=False` and set the `AutoSizeRowsMode=None` for the DataGridView since my columns needed to be resizable.

Comment: I refactored my datagridview to use a bindinglist backed datasource and ran into this problem again. When using a datasource, I noticed that no individual style changes were taking effect so it seemed that some event was reverting my style changes back to the column default style. Therefore, the second half of this solution was to add these changes to the DataGridView::CellFormatting event handler so they wouldn't be replaced with the defaults. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25207370/6525639

Answer (score 4):

Put the button to the right and ready

```
DataGridViewCellStyle  dataGridViewCellStyle2 = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
dataGridViewCellStyle2.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 1000, 0);
row.Cells["name"].Style = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Tobias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29010384/74585) I made a small static helper method to hide the contents of the cell by adjusting it's padding.

Be aware though that the button is still "clickable" in that if the user selects the cell and presses space it clicks the hidden button, so I check that the cell's value is not readonly before I process any clicks in my contentclick event

```
  public static void DataGridViewCellVisibility(DataGridViewCell cell, bool visible)
  {
        cell.Style = visible ?
              new DataGridViewCellStyle { Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0) } :
              new DataGridViewCellStyle { Padding = new Padding(cell.OwningColumn.Width, 0, 0, 0) };

        cell.ReadOnly = !visible;
  }
```

Comment: You could improve it by overloading the keydown event and ignore space when the button is not visible.

Answer (score 2):

Padding didn't work for me. I think it is easier and cleaner to just make the cell an empty text cell. VB, but you get the idea:

```
Dim oEmptyTextCell As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
oEmptyTextCell.Value = String.Empty
oRow.Cells(i) = oEmptyTextCell
```

Answer (score 2):

As an improvement to Sriram's answer, I would suggest just overriding the cell painting event and only painting the background.  I found that painting a textbox made it look a little odd.

```cs
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == yourColumnIndex && String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)e.FormattedValue))
    {
        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disabled a `DataGridViewButton` with a little effort as suggested in this post: [Disabling the button column in the datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525305/disabling-the-button-column-in-the-datagridview)

I preferred using a `DataGridViewImageColumn` and `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event to display different pictures as an image button could be enabled or not.

In this case, if button must be disabled you can display a blank image and do nothing on `DataGridView.CellClick` event.

Comment: the `(DataGridViewDisableButtonCell).Enabled` property doesn't update until mouse over, so this is too sub optimal, sorry

Comment: Try using a DataGridViewImageColumns as suggested in the answer.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it's not sufficient by way of explanation

Answer (score 1):

Handle custom painting and paint a textbox over there.

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == yourColumnIndex && String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)e.FormattedValue))
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        TextBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(g, e.CellBounds,
            System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.TextBoxState.Normal);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put padding all sides to the cell height & width (whichever is larger.)

Answer (score -1):

For a more simple solution it is possible to hide the column containing the button you want to hide.

For example:
`GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;` (First column)

Just count which column you want to hide starting from 0.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question. OP does not want to remove a complete column.