# How to hide a DataGridViewButtonCell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cells, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I have a `DataGridViewButtonCell` in my `DataGridView` and I wanted to set the property `Visible` to **True**.

I have tried:

```
DataGridView1.Rows("number of row i want").Cells("number of cell i want").Visible = True
```

Unfortunately it says that the property `visible` is `read only`.

Here is the **code**:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        'does not work
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(6).Visible = True         
End Sub
```

**Does anyone knows how I can achieve this?**

***Thanks.***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sometimes I want to hide buttons in a DataGridViewButtonColumn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200679/sometimes-i-want-to-hide-buttons-in-a-datagridviewbuttoncolumn)

Comment: Could you possibly set enabled to false, or simply ignore the click event for the button you want disabled.

Comment: Both are .NET `DataGridViewButtonColumn`s

Comment: @JohnG well i could but i was really trying to make it invisible because its for work

Comment: @JohnG i already saw that post but i didnt understand anything of the answer that was given there maybe is because i dont work with c#

Comment: Well.... since you obviously can not make it invisible with its Visible property... you are going to have to do something else.

Comment: i cant make the cell invisible, but what about the botton in it? that's my question...

Comment: Here is a link from MS just for this. [How to: Disable Buttons in a Button Column in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Comment: but i dont want to just disable it i wanted to make it visible = true

Comment: The first link I posted in the Duplicate comment… look at Tobias’s answer, it simply sets a different `DataGridViewCellStyle` to those cells. It uses `padding` to basically shift the button outside the visible area. I am aware this is C#, but the same thing would apply in VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual way to hide a `DataGridViewButtonCell`. Currently I can only see two options:

1. Use padding to move the button over as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29010384/6375113). I will provide similar VB.NET code
2. Set the `Cell` to a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` and set the `ReadOnly` property to **True**

**Use `Padding`:**

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(6).GetType() Is GetType(DataGridViewButtonCell) Then
        Dim columnWidth As Integer = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Width

        Dim newDataGridViewCellStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle With {.Padding = New Padding(columnWidth + 1, 0, 0, 0)}

        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(6).Style = newDataGridViewCellStyle
    End If
End Sub
```

**Use `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`:**

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(6).GetType() Is GetType(DataGridViewButtonCell) Then
        Dim newDataGridViewCell As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell

        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(6) = newDataGridViewCell

        newDataGridViewCell.ReadOnly = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Both of these *should* give you the effect of **not showing the button**.

Comment: thanks i used the DataGridViewTextBoxCell and it worked perfectly thank you !

Comment: @Halamahala not a problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a perspective issue. From a programmer’s perspective, simply ignoring the button clicks on the buttons I want to disable is very easy to do and takes just a few lines of code.

From a user perspective, this situation would play out like this… the user clicks what appears to be a valid enabled button, and nothing happens. The user did not write the code for this… so at best the user will think the computer is not responding to the button click or at the worst… would think your coding skills are dubious!

The same situation happens if the button is missing. The user is not going to know why it is missing… but will most likely come to the same conclusion described above with a non-working button.

In another very simple approach, let say that all the buttons are enabled and we have a list of the button indexes we want to disable. The users presses one of the buttons, we check the disabled button list and if the clicked button is one that is disabled, simply display a message box to indicate why this button is disabled. This approach says to the user… “Here are a bunch of buttons, guess which ones are enabled”…

The `DataGridViewDisableButtonCell` and `DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn` wrappers solve all of the above issues… the button is visible so the user wont question where the button went if you set it to invisible and it is greyed out. “Greyed out” is something most users understand and will relieve the user of having to “guess” which buttons are enabled.

You can create a wrapper for two classes: the DataGridViewButtonCell and the DataGridViewButtonColumn.

The link [How to: Disable Buttons in a Button Column in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to the MS example is one I have used before using C#, however there is a VB implementation at the link also.

Below is a picture of the result of using the two wrappers described in the MS link. For testing, the picture below uses the check boxes to left of the button to disable the button on the right.

IMHO, using this strategy is user friendly. If you simply make the button invisible or read only, then the user is possibly going to think your code is messed up and not have a clear understanding of WHY the button is missing or doesn’t work. A disabled button indicates to the user that the button is not available for that item. An option would be to have a mouse roll-over indicating why the button is disabled.

[image]

Comment: I do think by disabling the button it looks better than removing it or hiding it. This is what the OP should do.