# Hiding a value in a datagridview cell

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I want to be able to hide the second entry of a string in a datagridview cell.

e.g. Data in the cell will look like this:

```
Apples  1 

Apples  2

Bananas 2

Pears   12
```

but I want it to look like this (with the numbers hidden, rather than removed):

```
Apples  

Apples 

Bananas 

Pears
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you have any code?

Comment: What do you mean *hidden, rather than removed* ?

Comment: Set the visibility of the cell to false.

Comment: Maybe you can set the visibility of the specific DataGridViewColumn to false?

Comment: @KobyDouek By hidden I mean 'not visible'. Perhaps by changing the colour of the text after the space to white (the background colour).

Comment: Its not the whole cell, its the text after the space.

Comment: @Claire you can't change **part** of a string to different color.. that would be aweful. What are you trying to achieve exactly? Why not remove the numbers from the string?

Comment: @KobyDouek The text after the space is useful to me, but not the user.

Comment: OK, please read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the format of the column, and chage the text, like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("YourColumnName"))
        {
            string val = e.Value.ToString();
            e.Value = val.SubString(0, val.IndexOf(" "));
        }
    }
```

You must suscribe to the CellFormatting event of the datagrid. For more info about CellFormatting look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want to play with the color of the second word use this

```
void datagridview_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex  == 1 && e.Value != null)
            {
                string content = e.Value.ToString();
                string[] line = content.Split(' ');
                StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);

                SizeF[] size = new SizeF[line.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; ++i)
                {
                    size[i] = e.Graphics.MeasureString(line[i], e.CellStyle.Font);
                }

                RectangleF rec = new RectangleF(e.CellBounds.Location, new Size(0, 0));
                using (SolidBrush bblack = new SolidBrush(Color.Black), white = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        rec = new RectangleF(new PointF(rec.Location.X + rec.Width, rec.Location.Y), new SizeF(size[i].Width, e.CellBounds.Height));
                        if (i % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(line[i], e.CellStyle.Font, bblack,  rec, sf);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(line[i], e.CellStyle.Font, white, rec, sf);
                        }
                    }

                }

                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
```

Suscribe the datagrid to the CellPainting event.

Comment: Instead of removing the second value of the cell, how would I display the colour as white, but keep the first value of the cell black?

Comment: I edited the answer to your needs, I tested it myself. It works!

Comment: If this worked for you, please, mark the answer as correct and vote for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Split` function of string. Split function will split your string with given character parameter. For example cell.value.split(' ')[0].
https://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the number **invisible** on white background, without removing it from the string, you can use this trick:

```
string[] arr = cell.Text.Split(' ');
cell.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string.Format("{0} <font color='{1}'>{2}</font>", arr[0], arr[1], e.sub.backcolor));
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not a web application so I cannot use 'HttpUtility'. Could I do something similar but assign the second part to 'e.sub.backcolor'?

Comment: What is `e.sub.backcolor` ?

Comment: The background colour of the datagridview cell

Comment: See my updated answer. It might not work since I cannot see your code, but that is the direction.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the numbers are at a fixed position inside the cells. If so, you could use padding to shrink the display area of the cell, like I described in my answer on [sometimes I want to hide buttons in a DataGridViewButtonColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29010384/2505186)

Answer (score 0):

.NET won't let you set the .Visible property of an individual cell; only the entire column.
I have tricked out individual cells to seem invisible by setting the background color to that of the DataGridView. Eg, where my DataGridView is named dgvAccounts:

```
cells[2].Style.BackColor = dgvAccounts.BackgroundColor;
```